# How to write a test case using junit/mockito for while loop

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a method for which i need to write a test case

```
List<ProductDetailsResponse> getProductDetailsList(final List<String> productsCinList, final String fields,
            final String shiptos) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int count = 0;
        List<ProductDetailsResponse> productDetails = new ArrayList<>();
        String productStr = productsCinList.stream().limit(Long.parseLong(productCinProcessingLimit))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

        while (!(productStr.isEmpty())) {
            List<CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<List<ProductDetailsResponse>>>> productDetailCompletableFuture = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < noOfProductThread; i++) {
                if (!(productStr.isEmpty())) {
                    productDetailCompletableFuture.add(getCardinalProductDetails(productStr, shiptos, fields));
                    productStr = productsCinList.stream().skip(++count * Long.parseLong(productCinProcessingLimit))
                            .limit(Long.parseLong(productCinProcessingLimit)).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
                }
            }
            productDetailCompletableFuture.forEach(prd -> CompletableFuture.allOf(prd).join());
            if (!productDetailCompletableFuture.isEmpty()) {
                for (CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<List<ProductDetailsResponse>>> prd : productDetailCompletableFuture) {
                    if (null != prd && prd.get().getStatusCode().equals(org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.OK)) {
                        productDetails.addAll(prd.get().getBody());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I am not sure what to write for this.

Comment: you don't test loops, you test the method(s) they're in. create a test class, create mocks if you need them, configure those mocks and call the method with the test-input, later assert the result with the expected result

Comment: Can you separate out your methods into separate loops? Refactoring code based on single responsibility principle is the best idea to go.

Comment: if you are planning to write an unit test for getProductDetailsList() method then you are suppose to test the output of the function (in this case List<ProductDetailsResponse>) not the internal part. perform some assertion according to your needs on the list that is the way it should be done.

Comment: as @Stultuske say, we don't test loops, so create a test methods with different cases for example where  _productStr is empty_  and where it contains elements, and where _productDetailCompletableFuture is empty_   and where it contains elements, and assert if the expected result is returned